# Issue moving new item to newly added list until I do page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using a jquery template for dynamically creating a list (columns) which has different items (they are also added dynamically) and also created a plugin which helps moving items from one list to 2nd or 3rd i.e. using jquery ui drag & drop, but having a problem while dropping the item to the newly added list.

Scenario: When I click add list button, it creates list on the page. So I added a list named 'list1' and each list have a button to add items on the list so by pressing it twice I added 2 items on 'list1'. And items are moveable/draggable/dropable. Now added a 2nd list named 'list2'. So if I try to move an item from 'list1' to 'list2' it doesn't do that instead the item moves to 'list1'. This is happening without page reload, but if I refresh the page and do the same action now the item can be moved to 'list2'. Here is the code that I am using the for drag and drop purposes is here (the following code is placed in my jquery plugin):

```
var id = $('.' + options.dropID);
            var id0 = options.dropID;

            $('.' + options.dropID).sortable({

                helper: "clone",
                revert: "invalid", // go back to original droppable when drop outside drop area
                connectWith: '.' + options.dropID,
                over: function (event, ui) {

                    // may be usefull
                    var sortableElement = this;

                    var dataToSave = {
                        name: ui.item.text(),
                        objid: ui.item.attr('title'), // id has changed for array so use original id stored in title
                        thisID: $(sortableElement).attr('id'),
                        array: $(sortableElement).sortable("serialize")
                    };

                    // save the new data
                    saveData(dataToSave);
                }
            });
```

so I noticed a behaviour that the different behaviour is here:
- added an item and no page load, it add following div

```
<div id="337" class="cardItem droppable">         </div>
```

so if i try to add item here it doesn't allow me.

- after page load, it modify the above div to:

it adds ui-sortable to class attribute. So I try to search how or when this `ui-sortable` is added, it is done by jquery's sortable method.

and on page load I am calling the plugin like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind("load", function () {
            $('.laneList').ListDragandDrop();
        });
    </script>
```

I also calling the ListDragandDrop() after adding the new list or item but it doesn't add `ui-sortable` to the div, and I have to refresh the page so it can make 'list2' dropable. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or what should I modify to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery sortables seems to have been fixed in the latest version for items added after the creation.  If you're still seeing this problem, please add a jsfiddle so we can help with debugging.